# How can I add multiple SVN Hooks

Tags: svn, hook, svn-hooks

I've got several (in this case, pre-commit) hooks that I would like to have run during the same event. Right now, they are all just shell-scripts, so I know I could just concatenate them to get them all to run. In the future though, additional scripts may be written in Perl, PHP, or some other language as well.

How can I run several different scripts as part of a single hook, and have any one failure of the sub-hooks, fail as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much like @Gnustavo's Perl-based solution, I've also found some other (PHP-based) systems, such as

- https://github.com/kore/php-commit-hooks
- http://jeanmonod.github.com/php-svn-hook/

Both projects (and other 'SVN Hooks') will fail a commit if there's a failure of the tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can just invoke each script from the single pre-commit script in SVN:

```
#!/bin/sh

sh do_this.sh
php do_that.php
...
```

You don't even need to mention the executable names (`sh` or `php`) if you use a proper shebang in your scripts.

Comment: the exit(1) (or 0) from the success/failure of the individual tests do not propagate out of the sub-tests though, so the entire set of tests either return the default 0, or whatever else may be returned from the top-level script.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [SVN::Hooks](http://search.cpan.org/dist/SVN-Hooks/lib/SVN/Hooks.pm) Perl module which lets you implement and integrate many hooks in a single configuration file, which can even be kept versioned in the same repository.

(Disclosure: I'm the author of that module.)